# After jQuery UI (sortable, resizable): Cannot marker the text anymore

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

after I implemented jQuery UI functions like sortabable and resizable, I cannot marker the text anymore (markering text: Left Mouse Click and dragging the mouse).

I testet already: Without the following code, I can marker all texts.

```
$( ".panelcontent" ).resizable({
    handles: \'s\',
    stop: function(e,ui) {
        $.cookie(this.id, ui.size.height, { expires: 1825 });
    }
});
$( ".togglepanelcontent" ).click(function() {
    var icon = $( this );
    icon.closest( ".panelgroup" ).find( ".panelcontent" ).slideToggle();
    icon.closest( ".panelgroup" ).find( ".panelheadbar" ).toggleClass("panelheadbar_m");
    icon.text(icon.text() == "+" ? "--": "+");
});

$( ".padding_10px" ).sortable({
    handle: ".panelheadbar",
    helper: "clone",
    appendTo: ".content",
    connectWith: ".left, .right"
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Because of this: http://api.jqueryui.com/disableselection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove .disableSelection(); and it should work again.